# C# : How to save Dictionary<string, string> in datatable and dataset in XML file locally

Tags: c#, xml

How can I store a dictionary object of type `<string, string>` using the datatable and dataset in XML file? I am able to save text field value but not able to store and retrieve dictionary data.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use linq2xml.

For example, you have dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "1", "aa" }, { "2", "bb" }, { "3", "cc" }
};
```

Save it to xml file:

```
var doc = new XElement("dict");

foreach (var pair in dict)
    doc.Add(new XElement("pair",
        new XElement("key", pair.Key), new XElement("value", pair.Value)
    ));

doc.Save("test.xml");
```

Load from xml file to dictionary:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");

dict = xml.Elements("pair")
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Element("key").Value, e => e.Element("value").Value);
```